# Comparing occurrences of characters in a string C++

Tags: c++

I am moving from Python to C++ and I am not well versed with the latter.

I have a string s, which contains exactly one character "a" and one character "b" while the other characters are redundant.
I want to know whether "a" occurs first or "b" does.
In Python, I would do it something like this

```
s = "??a????b"
if s.find("a") < s.find("b"):
    print("a")
else:
    print("b")
```

Also, for C++, I tried this:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace as std;

int main(){

    string s;
    cin >> s;
    bool isTrue = 1;
    for(int i =0; i < s.size(); i++){

        if(s[i] == "a"){break;}
        else if(s[i] == "b"){isTrue = 0; break;}

    }
    cout << (isTrue ? "a" : "b") << endl;

}
```

But it gives an error pointing to the comparison between s[i] and "a" saying integer cannot be compared with a pointer. Kindly explain what is happenning.

I searched for find() function in c++ but things got out of bounds for me very soon. So kindly try explaining me using as less jargon and advanced libraries as possible **how to solve the problem** and **what was wrong in my code**.

P.S.: I am learning competitive programming so please don't be shocked to see that `include<bits/stdc++.h>` up there.

Comment: In C++, a string is a sequence of characters, and a single character and a one-character string are not the same thing. The former is spelled `'a'` and the latter `"b"`.

Comment: Unrelated, but helpful reading: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) Put them together and you can get into big trouble in a very short amount of time.

Comment: Even if you're learning "_competitive programming_" you shouldn't be using `<bits/stdc++.h>`. Learn how to use the proper headers and you'll be a competitor in the real world instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `std::string.find()` member function with a single `char` argument – the version (4) overload [shown here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

```cpp
#include <iostream> // NEVER use the <bits/stdc++.h> header file!
#include <string>
using std::cout;    // Also not best practice to use "using namespace std"
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    bool isTrue = s.find('a') < s.find('b');
    cout << (isTrue ? "a" : "b") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you can use the following 'shorter' form for multiple `using` statements, if you are using the C++17 (or later) Standard:

```cpp
using std::cout, std::cin, std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

The comparator should be `s[i] == 'a'` - single quotes. The double quotes denote a string:

```
"a" - string (= array of chars)
'a' - char
```

In expression like `s[i] == "a"` the **char s[i]** is compared to the **C-string "a"** (which is of type `const char[2]` and contains `{'a', '\0'}`) and this is an error, because comparing single characters to array of characters is not defined.

`std::string` also has a `find` method which searches for substring, so you could do something like:

```
if (s.find("a") < s.find("b")) ...
```

If 'a' or 'b' are not present then find would return `strind::npos` and would need to be checked first, for example:

```
auto pos_a = s.find("a");
auto pos_b = s.find("b");

if (pos_a != string::npos && pos_b != string::npos)
  return pos_a < pos_b;
else 
  throw std::runtime_error("a or b not present");
```

Comment: Not important here, but `"a"` is a constant array of characters. A bit of a nasty surprise when it does become important, so forewarned is forearmed.

Comment: of course. probably throwing would make more sense, but it depends on requirements. updated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `find` method of std::string:

(more up2date reference) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

or

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

```
size_t posa = s.find('a');
size_t posb = s.find('b');

if (posa == string::npos)
{
    cout << "a not found" << endl;
}
else if (posb == string::npos)
{
    cout << "b not found" << endl;
}
else if (posa < posb)
{
    cout << "a is before b" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

basically string is like array of character, so if you want to compare a particular index character of string, you can only compare it to character type, for representing character type use like

```
char ch = 'a'; //character
string s = "many" //array of characters , i.e 'm', 'a', 'n', 'y'
```

so if you want to compare a particular index value of string then you compare like this

```
if(s[0] == 'a') {
    //your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the logic of your Python version is clean enough, so you can get a first cut by just fixing the syntax, but keeping the logic the same:

```
std::string s = "??a????b";
if (s.find('a') < s.find('b'))
    std::cout << "a";
else
    std::cout << "b";
```

From there, a lot depends on the sort of situation in which you're using this code. If you're really sure the input will always be "good" (will contain both an `a` and a `b`, in this case), that may be perfectly good, finished code.

On the other hand, C++ tends to be used in larger, longer-lived projects than Python. Especially if you're trying to learn C++ with the idea of using it professionally, you may want to start putting a bit more effort into checking inputs than you're accustomed to doing in Python. Hard to guess about that though.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str = "";
    std::cin >> str;
    bool found = false;

    for (auto s : str) {
        if (s == 'a') {
            std::cout << 'a' << "\n";
            found = true;
            break;
        }

        if (s == 'b') {
            std::cout << 'b' << "\n";
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    !found && std::cout << "Not found!" << "\n";
}
```

> [Range-based for
> loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)
> [auto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto)
> [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)
> [iostream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream)

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use `s.find('a') < s.find('b')` just like in python, but consider a case where the string is very large and `a` is found early in the string and `b` is somewhere at the end. That test would still have to scan the whole string to find that `b`.

Another option is to use the standard algorithm [`std::find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of) which scans your string and returns as soon as either `a` or `b` is found and it's therefore cheaper in terms of CPU cycles. Also, the name of the function makes it clear to everyone reading the code what you are doing.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str = "??a????b";      // your input string
    std::string letters_to_find("ab"); // the letters

    // get an iterator to the first "a" or "b"
    auto it = std::find_first_of(str.begin(), str.end(),
                                 letters_to_find.begin(), letters_to_find.end());

    if(it != str.end())            // safety check if neither "a" nor "b" is found
        std::cout << *it << '\n';  // print "a" or "b"
}
```